# Connect to database from another container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Please help me if it's possible.

I need to start 2 applications with a single database.

I have 2 applications. First domain.com, 2-nd api.domain.com. Each application has docker-compose.yaml files.

domain.com - CMS

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  web:
    container_name: domain_web
    build:
      context: ./docker/php
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    #command: composer install
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
      - ./docker/php/app.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
      - ./docker/php/hosts:/etc/hosts
    networks:
      domain:
        ipv4_address: 10.9.0.5

networks:
  domain:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 10.9.0.0/16
          gateway: 10.9.

volumes:
  bel_baza:
```

api.domain.com - Laravel 5.6

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  web:
    container_name: api_domain_web
    build:
      context: ./docker/php
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www/html
#    command: composer install
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
      - ./docker/php/app.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
      - ./docker/php/hosts:/etc/hosts
    networks:
      api_domain:
        ipv4_address: 10.15.0.5
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    container_name: api_domain_db
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: domain
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: user

    volumes:
      - api_domain_baza:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./docker/db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

    networks:
      api_domain:
        ipv4_address: 10.15.0.6

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    container_name: api_domain_pma
    networks:
      api_domain:
        ipv4_address: 10.15.0.7
  redis:
    image: redis:3.0
    container_name: api_domain_redis
    networks:
     api_domain:
        ipv4_address: 10.15.0.10
networks:
  api_domain:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 10.15.0.0/16
          gateway: 10.15.0.1

volumes:
  api_domain_baza:
```

api_domain started successfully.

I need to connect domain.com with database `api_domain_db`. For connecting host, I used IP address 10.15.0.6. First application not connected to the database from 2nd application.

What is my problem?

How I can connect domain.com with the database of 2nd application?

Answer (score 0):

your problem is your are using separate docker compose applications for each application. And by default those applications can not access each other inner parts:

```
By default Compose sets up a single network for your app. Each container for a service joins the default network and is both reachable by other containers on that network, and discoverable by them at a hostname identical to the container name.
```

doc is here - https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

So it is like it creates separate network for each docker compose.

1. if you want them both to see each other inner part you can create external docker network as this:

```
docker network create --subnet 10.1.0.0/24 network_name
```

2. and then use that network in both docker compose like this:

```
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: network_name
services:
.....
```

3. if you need fixed IPs, you can define them as

```
   app:
    image: ...
    networks:
      default:
        ipv4_address: 10.1.0.10
```